# Подсчет количества и частоты выпаданий конкретного элемента массива " PHP "

Tags: php

Как посчитать, сколько раз был выведен и какова в результате частота выпадания определенного элемента массива.?

Вот мой код:

```
$a = ["a","b","c","f","e","t","y","q","z","w"];

$b = count($a);

for($i = 0; $i <= 10; ++$i){

       $c = mt_rand(0,$b - 1);
       echo " Echod - \" " . strtoupper($a[$c])." \"<br>";
   }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Из Вашего кода, можно что-то примерно такое придумать:

```
$a = ["a","b","c","f","e","t","y","q","z","w"];

$b = count($a);
$chances = [];
$iterations = 10;
for($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; ++$i){
       $c = mt_rand(0, $b - 1);
       $chances[$a[$c]] = empty($chances[$a[$c]]) ? 1 : $chances[$a[$c]] + 1;
       echo " Echod - \" " . strtoupper($a[$c])." \"<br>";
}

foreach($chances as $litera => $count) {
    echo $litera . ": " . ($count / $iterations * 100) . "%<br>";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! ;)